# Nested List within Bootstrap 4

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I have a table with the following information:

```
Name    | Address
John    | 6432 Newcastle Way
Rob     | 893 Lake Point St
Rob     | 1900 Harbor Lane
Rob     | 124 Marginal St
```

I am trying to create a nested list... That is, to show two total rows (one for John, one for Rob) and within the row, have another list showing each distinct Address (so Rob has 3 lines within his row).

This output is not giving me unique values and is not grouping them... any ideas how to tweak this or any walkthroughs I can find?

Views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView,ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .models import Book

class BookList(ListView):
    queryset = Book.objects.all().distinct('name')
```

HTML Try 1

```
<ul class="list-group">
    {% for book in object_list %}
    <li style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ book.name }}</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{ book.address }}</h6>
        <a href="{% url 'books_cbv:book_edit' book.id %}">Edit</a>
        <a href="{% url 'books_cbv:book_delete' book.id %}">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

HTML Try 2

```
<table>
{% for book in object_list %}
    <li>{{ book.name }}
      <li>
          {{ book.address }}
      </li>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='none')
    birthdate = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='none')
    deathdate = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='none')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='none')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('books_cbv:book_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk}) 

    def make_list(self):
        def append_children(parent, self):
            children = [[x['address']] for x in d if x['name'] == parent[0]]
            if children:
                parent.append(children)
                for child in children:
                    append_children(child, self)

        results = [[x['address']] for x in d if x['name'] == 'top']
        for parent in results:
            append_children(parent, self)

        return results
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your question, if I understand it correctly you are trying to do a table like this with your example data:

```markdown
Name    | Address
-----------------
John    | 6432 Newcastle Way
Rob     | 893 Lake Point St, 1900 Harbor Lane, 124 Marginal St
```

If that's what you're looking for then you will need to change your markup.

### Markup issue

Table elements don't work off li tags, they have explicit tags for rows and entries as well as columns. Details can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

This would be an example of the correct markup with proper headings and rows for each of your data:

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <!-- These are table headings -->
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </tr>

  <!-- These are each row -->
{% for book in object_list %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ book.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ book.address }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>
```

### Backend data

Now you mentioned you are trying to get all the addresses associated with a name to show up. Personally I would do this one of two ways by having a function that iterates over all of your book objects and returns a dictionary that either

1. has the name as the key, and the list of addresses as the value, or if you only need that list for this one template,
2. have it be a dictionary with a key of the book name, and value of the addresses as a string.

For example:

```py
def get_addresses_for_name() -> dict:
    result = {}
    # Iterate through book objects and set result[book.name] to a list of addresses or str
    for book in Book.objects.all():
       # Gets existing addresses, and if key does not yet exist, set to book.address
       addresses = result.get(book.name, book.address)
       
       if addresses != book.address: # If other addresses already exist at the key
           result[book.name] = f"{addresses}, {book.address}"
    return result


print(result["rob"]) # "893 Lake Point St, 1900 Harbor Lane, 124 Marginal St"
print(result["john"]) # "6432 Newcastle Way"
```

There is likely a way to replace the `Book.objects.all()` call with a filter so you can just get the objects with a certain name, but I don't have a test environment right now to test out the right syntax. If you want to do that, then details on that can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters).

Once you have that code then make it a method on your book object, and you can do:

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <!-- These are table headings -->
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </tr>

  <!-- These are each row -->
{% for book in object_list %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ book.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ book.get_addresses_for_name()[book.name]}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>
```

This is a bit of a long winded solution, and not the most optimized but without knowing any other setup in your project this should work.

Also if that is too slow, you may just want to pre-fetch the address dictionary, and set it to a variable you can re-use, like so:

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <!-- These are table headings -->
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </tr>

  <!-- These are each row -->

{# Gets the dictionary of address values #}
{% set address_dict = Book.objects.all().first().get_addresses_for_name()[book.name] %}
{% for book in object_list %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ book.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ address_dict[book.name]}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>
```

Comment: So for the get_addresses_for_name() function, this goes in my models.py, correct? And then iterating through would just be taking my table and creating a dictionary out of it? I tried adopting this with another solution... posted my updates above

Comment: @RCarmody Yeah. Easiest way would be to make it either a method on the class, or a django filter (quite a bit more complicated if you've never used them). Django has a builtin for iterating over all models called ```<class>.objects.all()```.

Comment: @RCarmody Check the answer again for a more fleshed out version of get_addresses_for_name(), and see the last example for a more complicated, but faster way of implementing it.